# What algorithm should I use to get a mapping between two variables?

Tags: neural-network, classification, data, embeddings

I have a dataset that contains for every row, a list X of x items, that is a subset of X_total, and a list Y of y items, that is a subset of Y_total.

```
|Row|   List X    |  List Y   |
|1  |  A, B       | 1, 4      |
|2  |  A, D, F    | 2, 3, 6   |
|3  |  B, E       | 5         |
|4  |  G, W, N    | 1, 2, 5, 7|
|5  |  W, G, D, T | 3, 5      |
```

I want to learn a mapping of X -> Y, so that when new items x appear, I want to know which items in y are likely to appear based on past history. The dataset has ~4k rows.

So far I tried a simple Sequential Model in Keras, but with 2000 inputs and 4000 outputs the results are meaningless , I think there could be a smarter way. I think Embeddings might be a good path to follow, because they can group together items of X that "tweek" the same Y's.

Any suggestions ? Something like RNN's ? Any useful links trying to solve some kind of similar problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embeddings is a good way to go, however, the way I am thinking about embeddings, is that you can convert these lists to a form like A 1, A 4, B 1, B 4, by concatenating every element in list X to its corresponding element in list Y, and then learn embeddings, using word2vec model(example), however, I am not sure if this would be able to learn relationships where combination of items in list X might lead to an item in list Y. I think this aspect should be tackled while learning embeddings. You can also look at market basket analysis as one of the ways of solving this problem. This article provides an introduction to market basket analysis https://towardsdatascience.com/a-gentle-introduction-on-market-basket-analysis-association-rules-fa4b986a40ce